# Undefined offset importing Excel/CVS with PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Im trying to import a .CVS file with First name and last name. But what it only does is import it to just one column in my database. And i get `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ..insertimportres.php on line 91`
and that is `$enamn = $filesop[1];` that is complains on.

**SQL**
[image]

**CVS/Excel**

[image]

**PHP**

```html
<?php
 include ("connection.php");
  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $handle = fopen($file, "r");
 $c = 0;
 while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
 {
  $fnamn = $filesop[0];
  $enamn = $filesop[1];
 
  
  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO kandidater (fnamn, enamn) VALUES ('$fnamn','$enamn')");
  $c = $c + 1;
 }
 
  if($sql){
   echo "You database has imported successfully";
  }else{
   echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file you upload? It looks like the values are `;` separated, not `,` separated (as you specify in your `fgetcsv` call). Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO`, and see the top related question about preventing sql injection - a `'` in a name will break your INSERT query.

Comment: The content i want to upload is the CVS/Excel picture i added. I changed it to `;` and it now takes the Lastname1 to the next column `enamn`and thats good but then the next name dont want to jump to its own column, instead it continues on `enamn`. How do I do so that each name gets its own column?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the error means that it's trying to get the value at index 1 but the index doesn't exist. It means that somewhere in your csv there is no value for the second column. To prevent such errors assign the variables like this:

```
 $fnamn = isset($filesop[0]) ? $filesop[0] : null;
 $enamn = isset($filesop[1]) ? $filesop[1] : null;
```

If the index is set then it uses the value from that, if not it sets the value to null. Depending on your DB col definitions (if you have not null) this might fail also. In either case you can change null to whatever you need